# iTerm2 Custom Scripts in Python

Tags: python, api, iterm2

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://iterm2.com/python-api/tutorial/index.html#tutorial-index) to customise iTerm2 with a Python script.

For the first step, it says to: "*Select Scripts > New Python Script*". I have a Scripts item in my top menu bar, but clicking it doesn't do anything; there is no dropdown or anything.

Upon researching this, it seems as though the Scripts menu is populated by adding files to: `$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm2/Scripts/AutoLaunch`. So I've created a Python file there and copy pasted the first example from the tutorial into it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import iterm2

async def main(connection):
    app = await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)
    window = app.current_terminal_window
    if window is not None:
        await window.async_create_tab()
    else:
        print("No current window")

iterm2.run_until_complete(main)
```

Now, when I restart iTerm2, I can access the Scripts menu, but I get a notification saying that the script has failed. I've tried `chmod 777 <filename>` incase that was it, but I'm still getting the error. `cat /var/log/system.log` has no information either.

What can I do to get my Python script running when I start iTerm2?

Answer (score 2):

The **Script Console** log may help

```
Scripts > Manage > Console
```

Then select your script on left to see the log.

Your script worked for me on startup for iTerm2 ver 3.3.6 by dropping it in the AutoLaunch folder.